# Is there any proper way to give a shadow effect on the top portion of a card view in React Native in Android OS?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, shadow

I have a `Tab View` which is placed just above the system default navigation icons on the screen. I want to create a `Shadow Effect` on the top part of the view. I have tried many ways, but react native does have only `elevation` property in android. And the `elevation` property is capable of giving the shadow effect on the bottom and the sides. I don't want to use any library. Is there any possible solution to this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Dimensions, Image, SafeAreaView, View } from 'react-native';
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>

        <View style={[styles.floatingView, styles.floatingShadow]}>
          <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>Hello React native</Text>
        </View>

      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  floatingView: {
    backgroundColor: '#B4F8C8',
    marginTop: height * 0.94,

    // position: 'absolute',
    // left:0,
    // right:0,
    // top:0,
    // bottom: 0,
    height: height * 0.06,
    width: "100%",
    alignSelf: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  floatingShadow: {
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 10,
      height: 28,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.44,
    shadowRadius: 10.32,
    elevation: 26,
  }
})
```

[Also, the screenshot to have a reference of what I am trying to say,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZtSF.jpg)

I tried with the `elevation` property and other react native functionalities. You can have a glimpse from my code. If I place the `Tab View` on the middle part of the screen, I can somehow block the bottom shadow but could not implement the top one. Any guidance or advise would be greatly appreciated.